# list files that contain a string from file and modified date is last 7 days

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that contains a bunch of files that has pictures and the naming format is similar to:

```
kitty_BW.jpg
puppy_B_W.jpg
ball_BlWh.jpg
rope_bw.jpg
shoe_Bw.jpg
kitty_C.jpg
puppy_Color.jpg
ball_c.jpg
rope_color.jpg
shoe_col.jpg
```

to move the files that I need I created a list

```
kitty
puppy
ball
rope
shoe
```

so what I need is to move the files that are ***NOT*** in a TXT file list ***AND*** are older than this month.

I was starting out with this code

```
$file_list = Get-Content C:\photoList.txt
$search_folder = "D:\photos"
$destination_folder = "C:\Backup"

foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    $file_to_move = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder -Filter $file -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | % { $_.FullName}
    if ($file_to_move) {
        Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder
    }
}
```

but this only works if the whole name of the file is in the list and the file that is being moved is ON the list, but I want to move files that are not on the list and are older than this month so I can dispose of them.

**EDIT**

I've been trying all sorts of things but for some reason, it doesn't compare

```
$file_list =  "C:\FAphotoList.txt"
$search_folder ="C:\FAphotos"
$destination_folder = "C:\Backup\"

$first_day = $(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y / %m ") + "/ 01"
$list = (Get-ChildItem $search_folder | ? LastWriteTime -lt $first_day).name

echo $list | Select-String -Pattern  '0183444'

 Get-Content $file_list | % {
    $list2 = ($list | Select-String -Pattern $_)
    }
echo list2
echo $list2

#here is my problem
$list2 | % {
[array]::indexof($list,$_)
}

echo "final list"
echo  $list
```

the problem is that when i try to compare the list with     `[array]::indexof($list, "kitty_BW.jpg")`
it works, but when I try it like in the sample I get nothing.

**EDIT 2**

```
$file_list =  "C:\FAphotoList.txt"
$search_folder ="C:\FAphotos"
$destination_folder = "C:\Backup\"

$first_day = $(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y / %m ") + "/ 01"
$list = (Get-ChildItem $search_folder | ? LastWriteTime -lt $first_day).name

echo lista
Get-Content $file_list | % {
    $list.Remove(($list | Select-String -Pattern $_))
    }
$list | % {
    Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder
    }

echo "final list"
$list = (Get-ChildItem $search_folder | ? LastWriteTime -lt $first_day).name
echo  $list
```

gets me this error

```
Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At C:\FAphotos.ps1:17 char:5
+     $list += $list.Remove(($list | Select-String -Pattern $_))
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

so I was trying to cast to an array list, but that didn't work so I was trying lots of different things.

Comment: So you have two main tasks: 1) How to determine if a date is older than this month? 2) How to determine if a file's name contains some string? Once you figure those out, then you can start writing code.

Comment: To answer @Bill_Stewart's questions: 1) Look at `Get-Date` and the `DateTime.Add*()` methods.  Additionally, `FileInfo` and its properties. 2) Look at the `String.Contains()` methods.  If you google these things with `msdn`, you'll find the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of digging and asking, I finally got it to work.

```
$baseWorkFolder = 'C:';
$searchFolder = Join-Path $baseWorkFolder "FAphotos";
$destFolder = Join-Path $baseWorkFolder "Backup";
$LastYear = '1/1/' + $(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y"); 
Write-Host "LastYear: $LastYear";

[string[]] $fileList =  Get-Content "$($baseWorkFolder)\FAphotoList.txt"; 
Write-Host "FileList:`n`t$fileList" -foregroundcolor Green;

[string[]] $FilesInSearchFolder = Get-ChildItem $searchFolder -name;
Write-Host "FilesInfolder:`n`t$FilesInSearchFolder" -foregroundcolor Green;


$moveList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]
foreach ($file in $FilesInSearchFolder ){
    $moveList.add($file)
}


Write-Host "FilesInfolder:`n`t$moveList" -foregroundcolor Green;

foreach ( $fileName in $FilesInSearchFolder ) {
    foreach ( $empID in $fileList ) {
        Write-Host "`n`tComparing Strings $fileName - $empID = $($fileName.IndexOf($empID))";
            if ($fileName.IndexOf($empID) -ge 0) {
                 $moveList.remove($fileName);
            }
    }
}

Write-Host "Potential Remove List:`n`t$moveList" -foregroundcolor Red;

foreach ( $removeItem in $moveList ) {
    $removegcItem = Get-ChildItem -Path $(Join-Path $searchFolder $removeItem);
    Write-Host "`n`tProcessing $($removegcItem.FullName)";
    Write-Host "`tChecking if file is older than $LastYear" -foregroundcolor Green;

    if ($removegcItem.LastWriteTime -lt $LastYear) {
        Write-Host "`tMoving $removegcItem to $destFolder";
        Move-Item "$($removegcItem.FullName)" "$(Join-Path $destFolder $($removegcItem.Name))" ;
    }
}

Write-Host "Final list (Newer than $LastYear):";
Write-Host "`t$( ( Get-ChildItem $searchFolder | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $LastYear } ).name )" `
    -Foregroundcolor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black;
```

had to use hash set and another array because I got an error of not being a resizeable object.

I think I wasn't able to compare because I was comparing strings to paths.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2.5 main tasks:

1. Determine files that are older then `this month`, this task includes half a task: how do you get the first day of this month?
2. Compare which file name are **NOT** in the `.txt` file.

   ```
   $first_day = $(Get-Date -Format "yyyy/mm") + "/01"
   $list = (Get-ChildItem | ? LastWriteTime -lt $first_day).Name

   Get-Content C:\photolist.txt | % {
       $list.Remove(($list | Select-String -Pattern $_))
       }
   $list | % {
       Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder
       }
   ```

Not tested, please have a try, and let us know the result. Good luck! :)

Comment: This is PowerShell--there's no need for string parsing. Get first day of the month: `[DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-[DateTime]::Today.Day+1)`.

Comment: I know that, here I just need a date-formatted string to compare with, so I do it in the easiest way. String is valid to compare with. :)

Comment: It can be done, but it is unnecessary. You are working with `DateTime` objects. There is no need for strings.

Comment: Agreed, a `DateTime` object is more professional, but not friendly to newbies, `Get-Date -Format "yyyy/mm"` is more `powershelled` :)

Comment: I think teaching (and learning) the more correct technique is better than not, so we'll have to agree to disagree about that.

Comment: thanks for the replies, I have updated the question with updates. seems like now my problem is the comparison, any pointers as to why this happens?

Comment: The point is: you only get __one__ item at last in `$list2`. If you want to add all items to `$list2`, it's the correct command: `$list2 += ($list | Select-String -Pattern $_)`. And why do you want the index of item from `$list2` in `$list`?

Comment: @SystemError thanks, that was only a test to see if it had something to do with the way I was comparing, the remove command wasn't working with the array, and by your answer it was. gonna try